# java: is interrupting thread absolutely necessary

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

I am new to Java and using a code given by someone. There, at the end of the code, they interrupt a thread if it has not finished. I am measuring the timing of the code.

The problem is that the Java code first issues all the threads, and then at the end it interrupts. Is interrupting necessary? Can't we wait till all threads actually finish? Or may be just skip interrupting (these threads are running processes using process exec command and they will finish anyway).
Here is the relevant code. First the code for individual thread:

```
  String commandString = "./script.scr ";
  process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandString);
  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
  while ((lsString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(lsString);
        }       
        try
        {
            process.waitFor();
        }
```

Now the code of the part which dispatches these threads:

```
public void stopWhenAllTaskFinished()
{
    while(notFinished) {sleep(50);} //notFinished is class variable and somewhere else it will set to false. 
    //now finished.
  //Interrupt all the threads
    for (int i=0; i<nThreads; i++) {
        threads[i].interrupt();
    }
}
```

This function is called from main class like:

```
 obj.stopWhenAllTaskFinished()
```

I greatly appreciate any insight or answer.

Comment: Unfortunately your description is too vague. The interruption may or may not be needed. It all depends on what the `Thread` does.

Comment: I have added the relevant code

Comment: Honestly it looks like a paranoid check for something that never happens.

Comment: @trutheality Thanks, but actually, notFinished is class variable which is set to false in another function. I will add that part. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: If the threads are coded so that they terminate themselves when they have no more work to do, then this whole polling thing is pointless. Just join all the threads and get rid of the while/sleep code entirely.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks. Can you please tell, how to know 'whether threads are coded for self-termination" ? My code for run function of each thread is simply what I posted here.

Comment: There's no way to tell without knowing how `notFinished` works. (For example, could there be a case where `notFinished` is clear but one of those threads is still blocked indefinitely in `process.WaitFor`? If so, you either need to interrupt it or fix that. Ideally, fix that.) It matters whether the threads are a pure AND operation (we're not done until all threads are done) or are a more complex operation (thread A did something so we don't need thread B to do it, even though thread B is trying to).

Comment: Threads are completely independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear whether the interrupts are needed from the code that you have posted.

- If `notFinished` is set to `false` when all threads have finished, then the interrupts are unnecessary.
- If `notFinished` is set to `false` when there is a possibility that some threads haven't finished, then it *could be* necessary.  Whether it is actually necessary depends on other things:

  - Are you prepared for the application to wait for the threads to finish naturally?
  - Can you be sure that the threads *will* finish?  (Could they hang / block forever?)
  - Do you need the results of their activity?
  - Will they respond to an interrupt?  (In this case, I think that the answer is "yes".)
  - Is there any harm in leaving the threads there?  (For instance, does it stop the application shutting down?)

Comment: 1. Yes, I am prepared. 2. Yes, they will finish surely. 3. No, I just the time of overall application (each task done on thread takes some time, but if interrupted: it is not good). 4. Yes 5. I don't know if there is a harm. My only requirement is: no thread should be killed before finish and overall app. should end only when all threads finish.

Comment: "If notFinished is set to false when all threads have finished.." I think, that is not the case. notFinished is altered before all threads finish

Comment: Answer 3 means that the interrupts could actually be harmful.

Answer (score 2):

The following code that Oracle provides in the javadocs is what most people do. AFAIK, this is designed to kill threads that refuse to shutdown gracefully after giving them a chance to shutdown.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

```
 void shutdownAndAwaitTermination(ExecutorService pool) {
   pool.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
   try {
     // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
     if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
       pool.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
       // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
       if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
           System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
     }
   } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
     // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
     pool.shutdownNow();
     // Preserve interrupt status
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }
 }
```

Comment: That's for a thread pool though - the original question doesn't use a thread pool.

Comment: Yes, the code uses: private PoolWorker[] threads. Can you please tell suitable code for this (or give a reference).

Comment: Sorry, I posted this before he posted any code. I'll look into the new question.

Comment: @Jon7 - your understanding is incorrect.  It doesn't kill uncooperative threads.  An interrupt can be ignored (or not even noticed) by the interrupted thread ... and that's pretty much what "uncooperative" means in this context.